# Sn.exe adds key pair but the project still doesn’t build

Tags: c#

We are moving our build machine to another server and we moved certificates used for strong name signing. I’m trying to add key pair used for signing assemblies using sn tools like this:

```
sn –i “C:\Certificates\MyCert.pfx” Key_Value_Pair_Name
```

sn tool reports that key pair is successfully added but when I try to build solution I’m getting following error:

```
Cryptographic failure while signing assembly ‘assembly name’ – 
the key container name ‘Key_Value_Pair_Name’ doesn’t exist.
```

Our solution is built on .NET 3.5 and I’ve tries using sn tool for .NET 3.5 and also for other framework versions but I still can’t get it to work.

Any ideas on what could be the problem is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You must add your key file to source control, because when you build, he serach to find your key but don't find.

Or you must adjust the path of your key file.